# Where to stream online Tiangong 1 descent?

Tags: space-station, tiangong-1, deorbit

Are there going to be good free live streams of the descent and if so is there much to be seen anyway?

Comment: How should a live stream of the descent taken if the place of impact is not known before?

Comment: Uwe - I would imagine having a prepared mechanism to accept input from watchers the world over could work. Complex, yes, but possible

Comment: Fly various drones and aircraft to take up-close images while showing an animation of the spacecraft disintegrating in the lower atmosphere while various experts and spokesman discuss the topic. Something similar to the powered deorbit of the Mir station would be so nice...

Comment: Drones or aircrafts are much to slow to follow a deorbiting spacecraft.

Comment: @Nigel, Tiangong-1 is moving about five miles a second.  The only aircraft that can even come close to that sort of speed are the X-15 and the SR-71, both of which have been retired.

Comment: My question is not how to film it but where to stream the event, and if there will be any live streams. Why would you think a camera needs to be moving fast or moving at all in order to film the station anyway? My point was that aircraft can be easily positioned nearby on a short notice, I never meant that something should fly alongside the station

Comment: @Nigel even now, less than a day  from when it is coming down, the uncertainty of when would finally deorbit is so high that you would need to have chartered planes ready to go at dozens of airports worldwide, and would still stand a decent chance of missing it because it deorbited over the mid-atlantic or pacific.